# Why am I not seeing my smart contract enter the blockchain?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I already linked both web3 and the metamask API using script tags, and I do not seem to be getting any type of errors in my console, so why can I not find my smart contract on the etherscan.io?

My JS is as so:

```
var dataHandling = async function customResponse () {
            const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
            if (provider) {
                if (provider !== window.ethereum) {
                console.error('Do you have multiple wallets installed?');
                }
            console.log('Access the decentralized web!');
            } else {
                console.log('Please install MetaMask!');
            }
        }
        dataHandling();

        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            web3 = new Web3($INFURA_LINK);
        }
        const SCabi = $ABI
        const SCaddress = $address

async function connect(){
            //Will Start the metamask extension
            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            const account = accounts[0];
            console.log(ethereum.selectedAddress)
            var dat = {
                fname: document.getElementById('name').value,
                cert: document.getElementById('cert').value
            }

var SC = new web3.eth.Contract(SCabi, SCaddress)
            SC.methods.setMessage(JSON.stringify(dat)).call(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("An error occured", err)
                    
                }else{
                    console.log(SC.methods.getMessage())
                    return
                }
            })
```

My smart contract is as so:

```
contract Message {
    string myMessage;

    function setMessage(string x) public {
        myMessage = x;
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns (string) {
        return myMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole code? Did you call the `connect()` method?

Answer (score 1):

`new web3.eth.Contract` does not deploy the contract. If you provide a specific address, then it is saying "I want to interact with a contract with this ABI, already deployed at this address". To deploy it, you need to use the [`deploy`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy) method. You cannot choose the address you deploy to, it is returned to you when the `Promise` returned from `deploy` resolves.

As an aside: I assume the `$` values come from PHP or something? It might be worth checking they are correct before you try deploying, if you haven't already.

---

**Edit**: assuming your contract is deployed, the problem is that `setMessage` is a method that modifies the blockchain state, and as such you need to use a transaction (to pay for that change with a small amount of ETH/gas).

The way to do this with Metamask/Web3 is a bit awkward in terms of API:

```js
// (from before)
let SC = new web3.eth.Contract(SCabi, SCaddress);

// first we get the call "data", which encodes the arguments of our call
let data = SC.methods.setMessage.getData(JSON.stringify(dat));

// then we prepare the parameters of the transaction
const params = {
  data: data, // from previous line
  // value: "0x0", // optional, only if you want to also pay the contract
  from: account, // the USER's address
  to: SCaddress // the CONTRACT's address
};

// then we start the actual transaction
ethereum.request({
  method: "eth_sendTransaction",
  params: [params],
}).then(txHash => console.log("transaction hash", txHash));
```

Comment: I already deployed the contract before, but when I try to call it's function `setMessage(x)`, I do not get any results. Also the $ values are not from PHP, I just made them to hide the address, API, and infura link

Comment: @ComplexEeno Ok, maybe I see why. Does `getMessage` work for you? `setMessage` is a method that changes the blockchain state, so you need to pay for it, and you need to make a transaction. See [Metamask's "Sending Transactions"](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/sending-transactions.html). I'll edit the answer with an example.